# How to find the servlet on the server in Sling?

Tags: java, servlets, sling

I uploaded bundle with the servlet to Sling

```
@SlingServlet(
        name = "Servlet for CRUD operations",
        methods = {"GET", "POST"},
       // resourceTypes = "/apps/practice",
        paths = "/content/practice",
        extensions = {"html", "json"}
)

public class CRUDServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
    @Reference
    private CRUDService crudService;
```

I can get it if I have "paths" at http://localhost:8080/content/practice. Perhaps a stupid question, but what do I need to type in the address bar to get it, if I have the "resourceTypes"?

PS Sorry for my English, I'm from Russia :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of deploying servlets in Sling:

- path-bound, like the one you have in your example
- resource type-bound

When a servlet is bound to a resource type, it will be served when accessing resource with that resource type. As a simplistic example, assume you have a resource at `/content/practice/hello` with a *sling:resourceType* property of value `practice/example`.

The servlet registration would have to be for `resourceTypes="practice/example"` and would be invoked when accessing the resource, e.g. http://localhost:8080/content/practice/hello.html .

For more details, see the [Sling documentation on resources and scripts](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) and also the [Sling documentation on URL to script resolution](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/url-to-script-resolution.html).

Comment: Maybe I do not understand something, but according to this logic my servlet without "path" property and having only "resourceTypes" should be rendered on  http://localhost:8080/content/practice.html. But this does not happen...

Comment: Try accessing the 'recent requests' web console page at http://localhost:8080/system/console/requests to see how your servlet is resolved.